# Calling jquery function

Tags: jquery

My code is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("Edit").click(function(){
    $.get('fetchvalues.php');
        });
    });
</script>

<input id="Edit" name="Edit" value="Edit Record" type="button" onclick="$.get('fetchvalues.php');" />
```

In the file "fetchvalues.php", I have written some code along with the javascript alert window to see whether the control reaches there. But nothing is happening.

Am I calling correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("Edit").click(function(){
```

This should be:

```
$("#Edit").click(function(){
```

And if you have that you don't need it again in the `click=""` HTML attribute.

Also try your debugging `alert` with:

```
$.get('fetchvalues.php', null, function() { alert('test'); });
```

Also it's not very clear to me where you put the alert() in your original code. In the HTML code outputted from fetchvalues.php ? If yes then it will never be executed; you would have to load the file by adding a  directive to your html file through javascript.

---

**EDIT**: Answering question asked in the comments here for better formatting.

> When we call "fetchvalues.php", how to
>   know it is being called.

You could temporarily erase all the code in `fetchvalues.php` and replace it with:

```
<?php print "Whatever you want"; ?>
```

After that, replace your `$.get` with:

```
$.get('fetchvalues.php', null, function(php_output_text) { alert(php_output_text); });
```

That should `alert()` "Whatever you want"!

---

Live demo: http://koper.wowpanda.net/so.html

Comment: @AndreasBonini the link of the demo has broken.

Answer (score 1):

You are making an HTTP request but not doing anything with it.

See [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) — you need to specify a callback.

Comment: At least the alert window must popup. Nothing happening.

Comment: Where and how to specify callback?

Comment: The documentation that I linked to explains (and has examples)